# Automating the creation of table relations in Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to automate the creation of all relationships in a database using VBA.

I have successfully found the code that can create individual relations and loop through a CSV to connect all single relations. The issue I'm encountering is when one field in the table needs to be linked to two foreign fields. I see I can do this manually but am having trouble locating where in the object the second relation is linked.

[image: Two Foreign Fields in Access DB Relationship Design View]

```
Public Function AddRelationship(strTable As String, strFTable As String, _ 
    strField As String, strFField As String, Optional intAttribute As DAO.RelationAttributeEnum = 2)

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rel As DAO.Relation
    Dim errorCount

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rel = db.CreateRelation(strField, strTable, strFTable,_ dbRelationDontEnforce)

    With rel
        .Fields.Append .CreateField(strField)
        .Fields(strField).ForeignName = strFField
        .Attributes = intAttribute

    End With

    db.Relations.Append rel

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:

    MsgBox Err.Description + " " + strTable + " " + strField + " " +_  strFTable + " " + strFField
End Function


Sub DeleteandAddAllRelationships()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim totalRelations As Integer
    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim columns As Integer
    Dim relationsToAdd() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer


    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set myWorkbook =_ appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ian.ebersole\Desktop\Relationships2.xlsx")
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    totalRelations = db.Relations.Count
    appExcel.Visible = False

    rows = 225
    columns = 7

    ReDim relationsToAdd(rows, columns)

    For i = 1 To 225
        For j = 1 To columns
            relationsToAdd(i, j) = myWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    myWorkbook.Close
    Set appExcel = Nothing
    Set myWorkbook = Nothing


    If totalRelations > 0 Then
        For i = totalRelations - 1 To 0 Step -1
            db.Relations.Delete (db.Relations(i).Name)
        Next i
    End If

    For i = 2 To 225
        Call AddRelationship(relationsToAdd(i, 1), relationsToAdd(i, 4),_ relationsToAdd(i, 2), relationsToAdd(i, 5))
    Next i

End Sub
```

It will successfully loop through any relations that are one field to one foreign field but will fail if the same field needs to be linked to a second field in the same table.

Comment: Relationship Builder appends _x to a tablename that is included more than once. I am guessing code needs to somehow use this same alias name. That or it cannot be accommodated at all because what you have is non-normalized structure. Why is this procedure necessary?

Comment: I'm using an ODBC data source that requires hundreds of relationships to exist in order to link two tables with the relevant data. I can do it by hand but was hoping there was a way I could automate the process. This code is just to test 225 of the necessary connections. I've not seen any way to import the relationships that already exist in the ODBC source.

Comment: The relationship builder does add what appears to be a new table with _x but if you double click on the relationship, you can use the "Edit Relationship" pop up and add a second row which can link the same field to a second foreign field with no issues. This is where I'm running into trouble replicating the process with VBA.

Comment: Those additional rows in the link editor would be for compound keys. Compound key is not what you are doing. So you did 'add a second row which can link the same field to a second foreign field'? Then close the builder and reopen. What do you see?

Comment: Using the example in the screen shot above, when I click Edit Relationship I see Table/Query: "Account" and Related Table/Query: "ARRRefundCreditCardRefundAppliedTo". Below that I see the fields "ListID" joined to "RefundFromAccountRefListID" and an additional row for "ListID" joined to "ARAccountRefListID". It shows a Relationship Type of One-To-Many, which I believe is what I'm trying to accomplish. When I click OK, I see the relationship as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: After a little additional testing, I retract my above statement that I want to do what you referred to as compound keys. That is definitely not giving me the right result.  Any further thoughts on your first note about appending the _x to the table name?

Comment: Try some code that checks if table name already in a relationship, and if it is append the _x suffix.

Comment: Maybe save table names to a collection object and search the collection to determine if table name already there? How many of this type of relationship are there? If you know exactly which fields need this, tailor the code to handle those specific relationships.

Comment: Looks like the issue was actually having a unique Rel.Name field. The default assigned name appears to just be the table and foreign table. so all I had to add was .Name with a unique name formula in the Add relationship function. Now I have all the relationships and just have to figure out how to make a useful query out of it. Thank you for the help! I will post final function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function that ultimately worked for me. Probably not the best error handling but it did successfully create all the relationships I needed when using the sub in my original post.

```
Public Function AddRelationship(strRelCount As String, strTable As String, strFTable As String, strField As String, strFField As String, Optional intAttribute As DAO.RelationAttributeEnum = 2)

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim db As Database
    Dim Rel As DAO.Relation
    Dim errorCount

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set Rel = db.CreateRelation(strField, strTable, strFTable, dbRelationDontEnforce)

    With Rel
        .Fields.Append .CreateField(strField)
        .Fields(strField).ForeignName = strFField
        .Attributes = intAttribute
        .Name = Trim(strRelCount + Left(strTable + strField + strFTable + strFField, 43))


    End With

    db.Relations.Append Rel

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:

    On Error GoTo NextError
    errorCount = 1

    strTable = strTable + "_" + Str(errorCount)

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set Rel = db.CreateRelation(strField, strTable, strFTable, dbRelationDontEnforce)

    With Rel
        .Fields.Append .CreateField(strField)
        .Fields(strField).ForeignName = strFField
        .Attributes = intAttribute
        .Name = Trim(strRelCount + Left(strTable + strField + strFTable + strFField, 43))

    End With

    db.Relations.Append Rel

    Exit Function

NextError:
    errorCount = 2

    On Error GoTo FinalError

    strTable = strTable + "_" + Str(errorCount)

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set Rel = db.CreateRelation(strField, strTable, strFTable, dbRelationDontEnforce)

    With Rel
        .Fields.Append .CreateField(strField)
        .Fields(strField).ForeignName = strFField
        .Attributes = intAttribute
        .Name = Trim(strRelCount + Left(strTable + strField + strFTable + strFField, 43))

    End With

    db.Relations.Append Rel

    Exit Function

FinalError:

    MsgBox Err.Description + " " + strTable + " " + strField + " " + strFTable + " " + strFField


End Function
```